# Wrong types when working with enum on querydsl

Tags: java, enums, querydsl

I have an entity annotated as

```
@Enumerated( EnumType.ORDINAL )
private CommentStatus cd_status = CommentStatus.DEFAULT;
```

My Q class generates

```
public final EnumPath<CommentStatus> cd_status = createEnum("cd_status", CommentStatus.class);
```

With the following statement:

```
QCommentEntity tableComment = QCommentEntity.commentEntity;
EnumPath<CommentStatus> o = tableComment.cd_status;
```

I get this error at compile time on `tableComment.cd_status`:

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from NumberPath<Integer> to EnumPath<CommentStatus>
```

Er, NumberPath? This is EnumPath type. WAT?

I have zero experience with querydsl internals. Why is this happening?

Querydsl 3.2.2

EDIT 1:
`$ mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose -Dincludes=com.mysema.querydsl`

```
+- com.mysema.querydsl:querydsl-jpa:jar:3.2.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.mysema.querydsl:querydsl-core:jar:3.2.2:compile
[INFO] \- com.mysema.querydsl:querydsl-apt:jar:3.2.2:provided
[INFO]    \- com.mysema.querydsl:querydsl-codegen:jar:3.2.2:provided
[INFO]       \- (com.mysema.querydsl:querydsl-core:jar:3.2.2:provided - omitted for duplicate)
```

Using `querydsl-jpa-3.2.2-apt-hibernate-one-jar.jar` for eclipse Q class generation

Comment: Some others have encountered this error when the classpath dependencies are not consistent. Do you have a working build without the APT generation?

Comment: I deleted the offending Q class and did run the maven build, the error was fixed. I deleted it again and forced APT generation (to reproduce the error again), the error was fixed ¬¬. Seriously, go understand eclipse. Now I have no idea of what happened, any clues?

Comment: I haven't experienced this myself, but some other Querydsl users have. It looks like the APT processor (code generation) doesn't get correct data when there are classpath issues. The APT errors mask other issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out to be some kind of classpath issue.
I could not identify exactly the cause due to the unpredictable nature of the problem.